# After upgrading AWS EKS (Kubernetes) to v1.23 from v1.22, Persistent Volumes (PVs) started failing to mount and pods got stuck in pending state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs, aws-ebs-csi-driver

**Problem:**

I upgraded from AWS EKS cluster to v1.23 from v1.22 and all of a sudden, all the pods that had Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) and Persistent Volume (PV) started failing with the errors like `FailedAttachVolume AttachVolume.Attach failed` and `FailedMount MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed` for the AWS EBS volumes.

Pods were giving the following error: `Unable to attach or mount volumes timed out waiting for the condition`

**Solutions Tried:**

- I tried adding AWS EBS CSI Driver add-on in the AWS EKS cluster but still it didn't work.
- I tried removing the annotation for migration to this new provisioner on PVCs but that didn't work either.
- I also tried adding storage class for `gp3` AWS EBS volume type with AWS EBS CSI Driver as the new provisioner as I was using `gp2` but that didn't work either.

**Note:** AWS EBS volumes were of type `gp2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding `AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy` AWS IAM policy to the AWS IAM role that is attached to all the AWS EKS nodes (AWS EC2 instances) and then adding the `AWS EBS CSI Driver` add-on in the AWS EKS cluster, errors were resolved and PVC got attached successfully. I don't see any issues related to Persistent Volume Claims (PVC), Persistent Volumes (PV), AWS EBS volumes, and pods anymore.

**Note:** I already had an AWS IAM OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider for my AWS EKS cluster which is a prerequisite for this. In your case, there could be some other issue and the resolution steps might differ so please check out the following reference document: [How do I troubleshoot issues with my EBS volume mounts in Amazon EKS?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-troubleshoot-ebs-volume-mounts)